# snap mirror for offline use

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, snap, snap-store

In my office environment we have several systems that are not connected to the internet. Using [`apt-mirror`](https://apt-mirror.github.io/) I am able to make Ubuntu repositories and PPAs available to all the machines on this "offline" network.

Is there something similar for `snap`?

Comment: [This](https://ubuntu.com/blog/howto-host-your-own-snap-store) might be helpful.

Comment: @mook765 thanks. if i read this correctly it will only setup a snap store and not mirror the actual snaps (which is half of what i need already!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [proxy store](https://docs.ubuntu.com/snap-store-proxy/en/) available. This runs on your own infrastructure and does the caching you require, although 100% offline is, according to the docs, currently in [closed beta](https://docs.ubuntu.com/snap-store-proxy/en/airgap). Note that this thing is a commercial offering, i.e. it costs money, and last I checked Canonical doesn't publicize exactly how much.

Comment: +1 to you for the information.  -1 to canonical for trying to break my offline network